# Find numbers divisible by 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the number of all $n$, $1 \leq n \leq 25$ such that $n^2+15n+122$ is divisible by 6.

**My attempt**. We know that:
\begin{align*}
n^2+15n+122 & \equiv n^2+3n+2 \pmod{6}
\end{align*}
But $n^2+3n+2=(n+1)(n+2)$, then $n^2+15n+122 \equiv (n+1)(n+2) \pmod{6}$, now we have

\begin{align*}
n(n^2+15n+122) & \equiv n(n+1)(n+2)\pmod{6} \\
n^3+15n^2+122n & \equiv 0 \pmod{6}
\end{align*}
I have done this and I think I have complicated the problem even more.

Comment: Are you looking for just integers or real numbers?

Comment: @bobeyt6 integers of course, saw the question and the attempt

Comment: @bobeyt6 Interesting, the question asks for *all* $n$ within $1\le n \le 25$.

Comment: I edited my answer and I apologize for my errors earlier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there with your first line. You have $n^2+3n+2=(n+1)(n+2)\text{ mod 6}$

$(n+1)$ and $(n+2)$ are two consecutive numbers so one of them is even. That gives you that this polynomial is divisible by $2$ for all $n$.

If $n$ is either congruent to $1$ or $2$ mod $3$ then $(n+2)$ or $(n+1)$, respectively, is divisible by $3$. Therefore all non-multiples of $3$ are solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even then $n^2+15n$ is even.  If $n$ is odd, then $n^2+15n$ is still even.  So $n^2+15n+122$ is even for every $n$.

So we just need to determine when the expression is divisible by $3$.

$$n^2+15n+122 \equiv n^2 +2 \pmod{3}.$$

It's easy to check that $n=1$ and $n=2$ are the only solutions.  So the answer is "all non multiples of $3$".  There are $8$ multiples of $3$ between $1$ and $25$, so the final number is $25-8 = 17.$

Answer (score -2):

**If $n$ must be an integer**: HINT: First, $n^2+15n+122$ is even for all integers $n$. Then $n^2+15n+122$ will be divisble by $6$ iff $n^2+15n+122$ is a muliple of $3$. So what integers $n \pmod 3$ is $n^2+15n+122$ a multiple of $3$?

You can tell working $\pmod 3$, that $n^2+15n+122$ is divisible by $3$ for every integer $n$ *that is not a multiple of 3*. [Indeed, $$n^2+15n+122 \pmod 3 = n^2+2 $$ $$= 0 \ \text{ if $n \pmod 3 \not = 0$}.] $$ Thus, $n^2+15n+122$ is divisible by $3$ iff $n \pmod 3$ is in $\{1,2\}$.

Thus, from this and the top paragraph, $n^2+15n+122$ is divisible by $6$ iff $n \pmod 3$ is in $\{1,2\}$.

**If $n$ is allowed to be any real number and not just integral:** Note that, as $n^2+15n+122$ is continuous on $[0,25]$, the function $n^2+15n+122$ in $[0,25]$ takes all values in $[122,1122]$. There are precisely $166$ multiples of $6$ in $[122,1122]$. As $n^2+15n+122$ is strictly increasing on $[0,25]$, it follows that there is at most one real number $n \in [0,25]$ such that $n^2+15n+122 = y$.

So  for each of these $166$ multiples $y$ of $6$ in $[122,1122]$ there is exactly one real number $n \in [0,25]$ such that $n^2+15n+122 = y$.